# Progress dailog doesn't show in the Lollipop

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm adding the progressbar to the my activity. my goal is to achieve to loading the progressbar until the data fetched from the web. So I write these code in my layout.

> question_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.majid.whiteboard.activities.QuestionActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_container_progress_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/prg_loading_question"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_question_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="#fff" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_ac_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_question_activity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> And QuestionActivity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
        initToolbar();
        //Dialog initialization===========================================

        final LinearLayout linearLayoutManagerProgressQuestion = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_container_progress_question);
        linearLayoutManagerProgressQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Bundle Initialization =========================================
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            faslId = bundle.getString("FASLID");
            BaseUrl = bundle.getString("BASEURL");
        }

        //RecyclerView Initialization ======================================
        recyclerQuestion = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_ac_question);
        recyclerQuestion.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(QuestionActivity.this);
        recyclerQuestion.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapterRecyclerQuestion = new AdapterRecyclerQuestion(QuestionActivity.this, questionha);
        recyclerQuestion.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerQuestion);

        // ========================== Sending FirstJsonRequest =================================
        FirstUrl = BaseUrl + faslId;

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(FirstUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject currentData = data.getJSONObject(i);
                            ModelQuestion newModelQuestion = new ModelQuestion();

                            newModelQuestion.setQuestionDate(currentData.getString("date"));
                            newModelQuestion.setQuestionDownFileName(currentData.getString("filename"));

                            questionha.add(newModelQuestion);
                        }
                        afterUrl = response.getString("pagination");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    adapterRecyclerQuestion.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    linearLayoutManagerProgressQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                linearLayoutManagerProgressQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

I set the LinearLayout in the xml to Visible.Gone and in the activity in the

onCreate set it to `View.VISIBLE` and set after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

to `View.Gone` . Every thing is `ok` in pre Lollipop devices, but Progress

doesn't show in Lollipop devices.